How to log the progress of .NET Static File Server
Has anyone seen a solution where they can inspect the progress of file downloads from the server side of an ASP.NET Core web application? The use case I have is:

A client GUI application spins up the web server with the code at the bottom of this post.
Another thread commands an IoT device to download the file.
The GUI application shows the progress of the download.

Is anyone aware of any hook or event I can use to inform some progress indicator on the GUI? Please let me know! Thank you very much.
Here's the code. It's a very minimal function that serves some static files using basic .NET Core:
private void RunServer(string configPath)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(configPath),
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        DefaultContentType = "text/plain"
    });

    app.Run(FileServer);
}

I've tried using the built-in OnPrepareResponse event, but that only shows the file request before the headers are sent and doesn't give me any insight into the download itself. I also read the docs for the static file middleware and I don't see anything that fits this use case.
Anything helps! Thank you again.

You could create a middleware that serves the files and announces regular events during read ops:

public class DownloadProgressAnnouncingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IFileProvider _fileProvider;

    public DownloadProgressAnnouncingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, string rootDirectory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(rootDirectory);
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var path = context.Request.Path.Value;

        if (path.StartsWith("/files"))
        {
            var fileInfo = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(path[6..]);

            if (fileInfo.Exists)
            {
                using (var fileStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream())
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[8192];
                    int bytesRead;
                    long totalBytesRead = 0;

                    // Read the file incementally so we can make progress annoucements
                    while ((bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                        // Raise some progress event here
                        Console.WriteLine($"Bytes read: {totalBytesRead} / {fileInfo.Length}");
                        await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}

Wiring it into a new netcore REST API project:

using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseMiddleware<DownloadProgressAnnouncingMiddleware>("C:\\temp");

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

In the above code, requesting http://yourhost/files/some.zip will serve some.zip out of c:\temp and fill the console window with progress announcements every 8kb or so

This is a really nice solution! Thank you.
